# Trouble recognizing kanji

Tags: kanji

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what this character is? I've typically never struggle with identifying kanji, but I've been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [再](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%86%8D%20%23kanji)
>   again, twice, second time
>   Kun: ふたた.び
>   On: サイ、 サ
>   (Jisho)